# htaccess redirect not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know I am missing something simple, but I can't get this redirect to work right. I have a parked domain that I want to redirect to the main domain. I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked-domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem is that parked-domain.com/anypage.html redirects to main-domain.com and leaves off the rest of the URL. I need parked-domain.com/anypage.html to redirect to main-domain.com/anypage.html

**EDIT**
I am sure this is a cache thing with my browser but after I tried the first suggestion then changed it back, now I get this:

parked-domain.com/anypage.html redirects to www.main-domain.com/anypage.html

but

www.parked-domain.com/anypage.html does not redirect at all.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but make sure and escape the '.' in your domain in the RewriteCond pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem was with the cache, that got part of the redirect working. I ended up using this to get it all forwarding properly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked-domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked-domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first one should have worked for all cases, but it didn't. Adding the second redirect fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ^ $ around your (.*)

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.main-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That caused a 404 error, the URL redirected to main-domain.comanypage.html